# I connected my laptop to a projector, and suddenly my desktop doubled itself!

Tags: 16.04, display, laptop, projector

I opened a presentation on my laptop, and connected the laptop to a projector.

Then, I opened Settings -> Displays. I saw two displays: my laptop and the projector.

I chose to "mirror displays", hoping that I will see the presentation in the projector.

Instead, on both my laptop and the projector, I saw an empty desktop!

After a while, I realized that, for some reason, my desktop has become two adjacent desktops.

The presentation was in the rightmost desktop, 
while only the leftmost desktop was visible on both the laptop and the projector.

I managed to "pull" the presentation from the rightmost desktop to the leftmost one.

However, this was very inconvenient.

Usually, when there is no projector, I only have a single desktop, which is much better for me.

How can I have a single desktop, that is visible in both the laptop and the projector?

Comment: Usually when you click mirror it copies whats on your screens to the other monitors so don't really know what happened.
For more information about external screens check out [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)

Comment: Maybe it was simple on a different workspace?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the situation on my system is the same on yours, as I managed to replay your issue at least 1 time.
With just 1 monitor attached (to DVI), the monitor (obviously) shows as Display 1 in the Display tool (**Identify Displays**). However, as soon as I connect the second monitor (19" VGA and situated right of 23"), it becomes Display 1 and the 23" is now Display 2.
If I then change from Extended to Mirrored, strange things happen. I also just barely saw my Display tool window on the edge, so I could pull it back to the center. When I changed back to Extended, in the tool the monitors have swapped position, Display 1 on the left.

I still have not found out what causes this strange behavior but I have a tip that at least worked for me:
As soon as the Display tool is open, I make sure to pull it to the left side of the screen. When I then select Mirrored, its easier to grab the window... 
I hope this helps.